# Persistent subscript placement with ot without superscript

Tags: amsmath, subscripts, superscripts

I have hit a problem regarding the consistency of subscripts, specifically while superscripting at the same element, i.e.

```
$a^{b}_{m+1}$
```

It seems that the subscript doesn´t have the same placement if I don't superscript the same element, i.e.

```
$a_{m+1}$
```

Here is an example, note the n and the n+2 have different vertical levels.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

$a^{x}_{m+2} \quad a_{m+2}$

\end{document}
```

Edit: The soluion I need is a general fix, and not always using an empty superscript when I only need a subscript.

Comment: They *do* have the same size; the fact is that “n” is less tall than the digits. To make the subscripts at the same height, use `\psi^{}_{n+2}` for the first symbol.

Comment: Please always provide code others can copy and test. Note that it is not the size that changes it is the placement. The size is the same. You might want to change the title accordingly.

Comment: `\fontdimen16` and `\fontdimen17` can be changed to adjust the positioning of subscripts, as The TeXbook page 179 says.
So you could do something like
`$
\dimen0=2.7pt
\fontdimen16\textfont2=\dimen0 \fontdimen17\textfont2=\dimen0
\fontdimen16\scriptfont2=\dimen0 \fontdimen17\scriptfont2=\dimen0
\fontdimen16\scriptscriptfont2=\dimen0 \fontdimen17\scriptscriptfont2=\dimen0
$`
There is probably a more LaTeX way of doing this though